# Angular filter not filtering on specific columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I'm trying to fix a page.  The issue is the filter is filtering every column off of a columns entered value.  So the entered product value will filter on product and client code or client code will filter on  product and client code.   How do I tell the filter these are separate values?

I'm guessing its with the formatting of the NG-repeat but I've tried several options with no success

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="productFilter" />
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="clientCodeFilter" />
</div>

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="product in filterData = ($ctrl.ClientProducts | filter : productFilter | filter : clientCodeFilter | filter : activeFilter) | startFrom:($ctrl.page-1)*$ctrl.itemsPerPage | limitTo:$ctrl.itemsPerPage">
    <span style="display:none"></span>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="col-lg-4 product" ng-model="product">
        {{ product.ProductCode }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 product" ng-model="clientCode">
        {{ product.ClientCode }}
      </div>
```

CodeBehind

```
(function (angular) {
  angular
    .module('licensing.clientProducts')
    .component('clientProducts', {
      templateUrl: buildTemplateUrl,
      controller: clientProductsController,
      bindings: {
        securityLevel: '<',
      }
    })
    .filter('startFrom', function () {
      return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
          start = +start;
          return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
      };
    })
```